# JavaScript Canvas drawing free

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am trying to draw on a canvas . (like in paint)But my code is not working. 
The function mousedown verify if the mouse is clicked and add the coordinates in vector.
Although it isn't drawing anything on the canvas. 
I stocked the coordinate in a vector and im trying to draw with the function redraw.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var ok = false;
    var clickX = new Array(); 
    var clickY = new Array(); 
    var clickDrag = new Array(); 

    var context = document.getElementById('Canvas').getContext("2d");
    console.log(context);
    $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e)
    {
        var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        ok = true;
        addClick(mouseX, mouseY);
        redraw();

    });

    $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e)
    {
        if(ok!=false)
        {
            addClick(mouseX, mouseY, true);
            redraw();
        }
    });

    $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e)
    {
        ok = false;
    });
    $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e)
    {
        ok = false;
    });

    function addClick(x, y, dragging)
    {
        clickX.push(x);
        clickY.push(y);
        clickDrag.push(dragging);

    }

    function redraw()
    {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 

        context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.lineWidth = 5;

         for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) 
         {      
             context.beginPath();
            if(clickDrag[i] && i)
            {
                 context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
            }
            else
            {
                 context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
            }
            context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi, you can try to use a fabric js. It's a wrapper for canvasjs. For me, it's easier to manipulate with canvas using fabricjs.

Comment: You are not setting `mouseX/Y` onmousemove

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

- jQuery's selector is case sensitive so you must use `$('#Canvas')`
- You need to calculate the mouse position in your `mousemove` handler.

**Refactored code:**

```js
var ok = false;
var clickX = new Array(); 
var clickY = new Array(); 
var clickDrag = new Array(); 

var context = document.getElementById('Canvas').getContext("2d");
console.log(context);
$('#Canvas').mousedown(function(e)
{
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    ok = true;
    addClick(mouseX, mouseY);
    redraw();

});

$('#Canvas').mousemove(function(e)
{
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    if(ok!=false)
    {
        addClick(mouseX, mouseY, true);
        redraw();
    }
});

$('#Canvas').mouseup(function(e)
{
    ok = false;
});
$('#Canvas').mouseleave(function(e)
{
    ok = false;
});

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
    clickX.push(x);
    clickY.push(y);
    clickDrag.push(dragging);

}

function redraw()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 

    context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 5;

     for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) 
     {      
         context.beginPath();
        if(clickDrag[i] && i)
        {
             context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
        }
        else
        {
             context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
        }
        context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="Canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But if i copy it in my files and run it in my browser it still not working. Do you know why?

Comment: @SpiridonAndra. I can't debug your (new) glitch from the code you have posted in your answer. I just did minor tweaks to your question's code and your question's code is running fine for me so the glitch must be in another part of your code. Sorry! :-//